# Filter Spark Dataframe with list of values in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am trying to create a dataframe from hive table using SparkSession like below. Once created I am filtering the rows by a list of Ids.

```
val myDF = spark.sql("select * from myhivetable")
val someDF =  mfiDF.where(mfiDF("id").isin(myList:_*))
```

Instead of this approach is there a way I can query the hive table as below:

```
val myDF = spark.sql("select * from myhivetable").where (("id").isin(myList:_*))
```

When I try like this I am getting a compilation error.

Could someone suggest a best approach for this. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `where($"id".isin(myList: _*))`?

Comment: Hi Leo C, When I try as such  I am getting an error as "value isin is not a member of String"

Comment: Add import spark.implicits._ before the line with $"id"

Comment: Can you try this myDF.filter(col("id").isin(myList:_*)) ?

Comment: Thank Leo C, It worked after adding spark.implicits._ .

Comment: Thanks Denis Makarenko

Answer (score 0):

You could also do an inner join to remove unwanted ids, something like below may work.

```
val ids = sc.parallelize(myList).toDF("id")
someDF.join(ids, ids.id === someDF.id)
```

Comment: Thanks Alberto, I will try like this and let you know